# Anyway to save an object to another user with parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

Im trying to create an app where you can follow users, I can save the userId of the user I am trying to follow to a "following" key in the user class. However i cannot save the current userId to a "followers" key for the user being followed. I get the error "User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp"

```
func followUser() {
    //User to be followed's username
    var userName = self.title!
    let myUserId = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId




    var query = PFUser.query()
    query?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: myUserId!)
    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let users = objects {
            for user in users {
                //thisUserId = objectId of user being followed
                user.addUniqueObject(self.thisUserId, forKey: "following")
                user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        println(error)
                    } else {
                            println("You favorited \(self.title)")
                            var otherQuery = PFUser.query()
                            otherQuery?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: self.thisUserId)
                            otherQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
                                if let users = objects {
                                    for object in users {
                                        if let user = object as? PFUser {
                                            user.addUniqueObject(myUserId!, forKey: "followers")
                                            user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                                                if error == nil {
                                                    println("You are following \(self.title)")

                                                } else {
                                                    println(error)
                                                }
                                            })
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            })

                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parse website seems much better equipped to handle this. There's nothing wrong with your code (although it is painfully nested and could use some functional abstraction)

https://parse.com/questions/user-cannot-be-saved-unless-they-have-been-authenticated-via-login-or-signup

Comment: Yeah I know it isn't pretty. Just was being a pain without nesting it all together